# Android Studio can't find my Google Play Services

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

I've been following walkthroughs and looking through sof questions for hours and none of the things I've tried have led me to an answer. Where should I look next?

## Error

```
Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/1.3.0-beta1/google-services-1.3.0-beta1.pom
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/1.3.0-beta1/google-services-1.3.0-beta1.jar
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/1.3.0-beta1/google-services-1.3.0-beta1.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/1.3.0-beta1/google-services-1.3.0-beta1.jar
Required by:
    MyApp:myApp:unspecified
```

## MyApp Gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.phone.MyApp"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':comcrashlyticssdkandroid_crashlytics_2')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+' // updated
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+' // updated
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+' // updated
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:+"
}
```

## SDK Extras

[image]

Comment: Does specifying the version change anything? Like `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`. Also, you shouldn't need to selectively compile analytics and gcm, if you're already including the base library.

Comment: I'd say all of that is fine. It looks like the issue is that the compiler can't find `google-services:1.3.0-beta1`

Comment: Oh, I'm blind, I didn't even notice your errors. I think you need to include `jcenter()` in your respositories.

Comment: @Andy Can you give me something to google? "jcenter android studio" brings up a lot of mumbo jumbo to sort through and I don't know that it's valuable.

Comment: `jcenter()` is the repository that contains Android libraries, like `com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1` which could not be found. All I see in your build.gradle is `maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }` which is only for the Fabric SDK? Under [Modify build.gradle](https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/android/integrating) contains a sample which might help clarify.

Comment: @Andy That did it. Thanks for your help and f you want to post that as the answer I'll make sure you get credit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`jcenter()` contains the Android libraries, you'll need to add it to your repositories.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter();
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    jcenter();
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add the dependency to your project's top-level build.gradle:
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'

//Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

//Set Up Google Play Services
dependencies {
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+"
}
```